# How can I reduce deflection in a steel stud wall?

Tags: shower, tile

I am installing tile on wall for shower. The framing is metal studs, unfortunately due to main line vertical cast iron pipes, I did not have a stud on one corner (which the backer board requires). So I added A stud myself, I fastened it to the existing track on bottom, but the top I had to rig a track for which it to seat in. Now after installing backer board I’m seeing way too much deflection. What are some ways I can improve the stiffness of this corner studs? Keep in mind I have no access to the walls behind this corner.

Answer (score 4):

How to do an unsupported [corner](https://housekeeping.tn/comment-faire-les-angles-en-ba13/) with drywall, backer board etc:

[image] [image]

Both sides of the corner support the other which and avoid deflection.

However you won't be able to do this if there is an annoying pipe stuck in the corner.

Next best thing would be to put a metal corner behind the boards like that:

[image]

...and another way:

[image]

This one is a bit annoying to assemble because you have to screw the right drywall on the stud first on the bench (because the screws are not accessible once it's installed) then play tetris and put the whole thing in. But it'll make a strong corner.

If the two pieces of drywall/board are not well bonded together, your corner will crack and it will leak.

EDIT: OK, so you'll go with the first one (corner metal):

The shop that sold you the metal studs should have corners like [this one](https://www.castorama.fr/corniere-placo-cr2-3-m/3496250009646_CAFR.prd) but they are not wide enough, so you'll have to put the screws near the edge of the drywall, which can then crack.

Personally I'd use a wider corner. Probably aluminium, since that doesn't rust, it's available in wider shape, and it's much easier to put self tapping screws in aluminium than even 1mm thick steel.

Something like 45mm wide corner profile. Then you can use self tapping drywall screws like this one:

[image]

The tip looks like a drill bit. That will make a hole in the metal and then the screw will tap its own hole.

Comment: Wow you got the problem down almost exactly and you’re right I can do the first drywall based solution because the existing drywall back there stops short of the pipe and I’d have to get back there to fasten which won’t work. Are there prefab Corner L’s or do I just need to get some custom steel from the local steel shop?

Comment: @JCuningham if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the appropriate way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote button next to _every_ answer that was helpful to you, then to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most__.

Comment: I like a thank you message better than an anonymous upvote XD I've updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pour gypsum (Gypcrete) behind the wall from the top plate area and encase the stud?